# how to increase size of icons in android studio bottom navigation layout

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-navigation-bar

i am having a hard time increasing the size of the icons of my bottom nav bar in android studio. is there any way i can increase the size of [this]. because it's extremely small i had to zoom in every time i try to run it. thanks in advance! [image: 1]

> bottom_nav_menu.xml

```
<item android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_homebtn_01"
    android:id="@+id/homebtn"/>
<item android:title="Courses"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_coursesbtn_01"
    android:id="@+id/coursebtn"/>
<item android:title="Challenges"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_challengesbtn_01"
    android:id="@+id/challengesbtn"/>
<item android:title="Flashcards"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_flashcardsbtn_01"
    android:id="@+id/flashcardsbtn"/>
<item android:title="Dictionary"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dictionarybtn_01"
    android:id="@+id/dictionarybtn"/>
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="411dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:background="#40B191"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this with your preferred value

```
    app:itemIconSize
```

Comment: hi! thanks for this, it now works, however, the text is now overlapping with the icon.. and i can't seem to arrange it, i have already used the `<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>` but it does not work